# Data loading on DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, .net, datagrid

I am using a DataGrid (.NET 1.1) to which data is being bound from data source which gets almost 3000 rows and 25 columns.  Because of heavy data, it is taking around 3 minutes to load data on to datagrid. I want to load first 50 records, then next 50 , then next 50... so on...

How can I achieve this ?.. I tried using Paging option but it loads whole records..

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the performance of the query?  Just making sure!

Comment: Hi Actually I am getting values in to my data source from 4 queries.. each query will fetch data in to some specific columns... I have seen the queries were executing well

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of functionality you are looking for?

```
    Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = DataRange(5, 25, DataSet1.Tables(0))
```

.

```
  Private Function DataRange(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer, ByRef SourceTable As DataTable) As DataTable
    Dim TempTable As DataTable = SourceTable.Clone
    If Max > SourceTable.Rows.Count Then
      Max = SourceTable.Rows.Count
    End If
    For i As Integer = (Min - 1) To (Max - 1)
      TempTable.ImportRow(SourceTable.Rows(i))
    Next
    Return TempTable
  End Function
```

As decompiled said, make sure the slowness isn't in your query.

Comment: Not really..... I am looking for something which will dynamically load  50rows first then next 50 rows... Is there any way we can implement Custom Paging ?..

Comment: Are you trying to load 50 rows at a time from database to dataset or 50 rows at a time from dataset to form? Is this for Winforms or ASP.NET? In your comment above, you mention filling your columns from 4 separate queries. Can you give a sample of this code? Why aren't you joining all of the data in the database?

Comment: I am querying from different databases and the conditions for those values are different from each other... I am using ASP.NET.. I want to load from database to dataset..